# How do I pop/apply selecting a file or hunks from file in stash using Magit?

Tags: magit, git

I need to select some files or hunks in one file in existing stash entry using `Magit`, and then apply or pop them. How can that be done?

The `git` command for a file (with 0 replaced by the relevant stash number) is:

```
git checkout "stash@{0}" -- <path-name>
```

Comment: Which action in this [method list](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Stashing.html) of everything you can do for stash using Magit would you like to call?

Comment: @roomworoof That is the issue. The OP and I don't know what is the command that corresponds to the equivalent of `git checkout "stash@{0}" -- <path-name>`. Ideally by pressing a key in the buffer viewing the stash

Answer (score 0):

Open the stash and then, just as in any other Magit diff buffer, type <kbd>a</kbd> on the hunks/files/regions you wish to apply.